# Weblogic MBeanServer provides the value only after 15 secs

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx

I invoke my custom Monitor registered on the Weblogic MBeanServer, but weblogic give me the updated value only after 15 seconds.

Does Weblogic cache call?

Answer (score 2):

found!

I marked my MBean with the following (spring) annotatioon:

```
@ManagedResource( 
        objectName = "bean:name=obuInterfaceMonitor", description = "obuInterface Monitor", log = true, 
        logFile = "jmx.log", currencyTimeLimit = 15, persistPolicy = "OnUpdate", persistPeriod = 200, persistLocation = "interfaceMonitor", persistName = "bar"
     )
```